# How can I serve html pages in R?

Tags: r, http, webserver, r-rook-package

I have a folder with html files and I want to start a simple HTTP server that serves the requested file.

I have been trying to use `Rook`, but it asks for an app function that generates the HTML response.

```
library(Rook)
server <- Rhttpd$new()
server$start(quiet=TRUE)
server$add(name="my_app", app="path/to/app.R")
```

I guess I could somehow tell the app function to read the contents of the requested HTML file and use that as the response, but there should be an easier way.

Comment: Why R to server HTML pages?

Comment: because I'm generating HTML pages in R and I wanted it to be an automatic process and cross-platform, but I guess I'll have to manually run something like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Comment: you may want to look at shiny http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a little old but I faced a similar problem and so thought I would post my solution here.

[Aside: I wanted to serve regular html/js/css via rook in conjuction with json responses to ajax queries with statistical solution - hence wanting to use R]

```
R.server <- Rhttpd$new(); # Create server

# Use a Builder to add a 
staticApp <- Builder$new( 
  Static$new(
      urls=c('/www/css',
             '/www/js/libs',
             '/www/js',
             '/www/img',
             '/www'),
  root=getwd()
))
R.server$add(app=staticApp, name="static")
R.server$start()
```

Essentially my working directory contained contains a folder called **www** which contains all my static resources (in subfolders css, js, etc). In particular if the folder **www** contains a file **index.html** then this can be accessed via **localhost:23702/custom/static/www/index.html**

Other apps for more R-focused operations can be easily included in the builders construction.

Not probably would be cleaner with **www** moved to root = file.path(getwd(),'www') and a recursive search for all subfolders.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's great, and I can get a stack HTML page to show using this method. But then how to process GET/POST requests from the client? I am trying something like the code below, but then how to know what URL for the GET/POST requests?# Use a Builder to add a 
staticApp <- Builder$new( 
    Static$new(
        urls=c('/app', '/app/library'),
        root = file.path(getwd(), "..", "..") 
        ),
    App$new(function(env) {
        req <- Request$new(env)
        res <- Response$new()
        getstr <<- paste(capture.output(str(req$GET()),file=NULL),collapse='\n')
        res$finish()

})
)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the example at `?Builder`.

You right, `Rook` expects you to provide an "app". An "app" however can be built almost as you want. And `Builder` comes into this.

The typical usage of `Builder` is providing:

1. the urls to the static pages (js, css, images, etc)
2. the urls to the dynamic pages that will be brew()ed via `brew` function, these can be `.html` or `.Rhtml` pages
3. the url to redirect your web application (the default, or index, page)